# Index out of bounds for an array list (java)

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, range

This is for a homework assignment. I am trying to make a program that searches a text file for specific words and then prints out the frequency of the word.

```
public class WordFreq extends Echo{

ArrayList<WordCount>array1=new ArrayList<WordCount>();
String[] words;
int wordsTotal=0;


public WordFreq(String f, String x) throws IOException
{
  super(f);
  words=x.toLowerCase().split(" ");
}

public void processLine(String line){ 
  String[] lines=line.toLowerCase().split(" ");
  wordsTotal=wordsTotal+lines.length;
  for(int j=0; j<lines.length; j++){
    WordCount alpha=new WordCount(lines[j]);
    alpha.incCount();
    array1.add(alpha);}
  for(int x=0; x<array1.size(); x++){
    for(int y=0; y<array1.size(); y++){
      if(array1.get(x).equals(array1.get(y))&&(x!=y)){
        for(int i = 0; i< array1.get(y).getCount(); i++){
          array1.get(x).incCount();
        }
        array1.remove(y);
      }
    }
  }

}

public void reportFrequencies(){
  for(int i = 0; i<array1.size();i++){
    // System.out.println(array1.get(i).getWord()+" "+array1.get(i).getCount());
  }
  int currentWord=0;
  for(int x=0; x<words.length; x++){
    for(int y=0; y<array1.size(); y++){
      if(words[x].equals(array1.get(y).getWord())){
        currentWord=array1.get(y).getCount();}}
    System.out.print(words[x]+" ");
    System.out.printf("%.4f",(double)currentWord/wordsTotal);
  }
}
```

}

Here is my main method:

```
public class FreqStudy{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter file name");
    String fileName = scan.next();
    Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter words to search for");
    System.out.println("enter lower case, separated by spaces");
    String wordString = scan2.nextLine();
    WordFreq f = new WordFreq(fileName,wordString);
    f.readLines();
    f.reportFrequencies();
  }
}
```

I am using a .txt file of the book Emma by Jane Austen. This is the error message that I get when I run the program and try to search for words:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 906, Size: 906
at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(ArrayList.java:547)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:322)
at WordFreq.processLine(WordFreq.java:26)
at Echo.readLines(Echo.java:16)
at FreqStudy.main(FreqStudy.java:15)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)"
```

Here are the codes for Echo and WordCount:

```
public class WordCount{

private String word;
private int count;

public WordCount(String w){
word = w;
count = 0;
}

public String getWord(){
return word;}

public int getCount(){
return count;}

public void incCount(){count++;}

public String toString() {
return(word +  " --- " + count);
}

public boolean equals(Object other){
WordCount i = (WordCount)other;
return (this.word.equals(i.word));
}
}
```

echo:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;


public class Echo{
String fileName; // external file name
Scanner scan; // Scanner object for reading from external file

public Echo(String f) throws IOException
{
fileName = f;
scan = new Scanner(new FileReader(fileName));
}

public void readLines(){ // reads lines, hands each to processLine
while(scan.hasNext()){
  processLine(scan.nextLine());
}
scan.close();
}

public void processLine(String line){ // does the real processing work
System.out.println(line);
}
}
```

Line 26 of my code is:

```
for(int i = 0; i< array1.get(y).getCount(); i++)
```

Comment: One of your loops is incrementing too many times. Can you mention which is on line 26 of WordFreq?

Comment: You are removing items from your array in a for loop. Try going through the array from start to end, which makes it safe to remove items at the current index.

Comment: It might help if we had the code to the `Echo` and `WordCount` classes as well

Comment: Which for loop am I removing items from my array in?

Comment: This is completely the wrong approach. Use a `Map<String, Integer>` and the entire program become just a few lines.

Answer (score 0):

In your nested `for` loops, you're looping against the size of `array1` at the same time as you're manipulating `array1`. Don't alter anything you're using to iterate while iterating. You might consider copying `array1` to iterate over.

```
for(int x=0; x<array1.size(); x++){
    for(int y=0; y<array1.size(); y++){
        if(array1.get(x).equals(array1.get(y))&&(x!=y)){
            for(int i = 0; i< array1.get(y).getCount(); i++){
                 array1.get(x).incCount();
            }
            array1.remove(y); // NO NO NO
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by copying array1?

Comment: @user2163240 [here's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6536128/264775) an example of copying a list. The idea would be to manipulate the copy instead of the list you're iterating over.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that your using `array1.size()` for your boundary yet inside the for-loop you are removing values from `array1`.  So your y counter is incrementing and your boundary is always decreasing.  At a specific point in the loop this increment/decrements is going to causing a situation where `Y` will become greater than `array1.size` so when you try to do a `get(y)` you will be out of bounds.

try something like

```
int size = array1.size();  //outside the for loops
....
for(int y=0; y<size; y++){
```

Comment: This will still blow up when the index of `y` is past the new (shorter) length of the `ArrayList`.

Comment: I tried this but got almost the same error message: 
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 23, Size: 23

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the object you are iterating over I would suggest using an [Iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html).

You can get the iterator over your `ArrayList` by doing this:

`Iterator<WordCount> iterator = array1.iterator();`

This could potentially solve your problem and simplify your code.  Just be sure to use:

`iterator.remove()` instead of `array1.remove(index)` etc.