# ConcurrentModificationException when trying execute MultiThread in batches

Tags: multithreading, list, batch-processing, executorservice

I am using ExecutorService for multiThread process - I have list of IDs, for every ID I make some part of code using threads.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);   
for (String id : listOfIDs) {
    Runnable worker = new WorkerThread(id);
    executor.execute(worker);
}
executor.shutdown();
....
```

Everything is working fine and results are as expected. But because I have lot of IDs, I need to do this part more effective. I have performance problem and it seems that it is because of creating lof of WorkerThreads. I have decided to run it for list of baseIds, and later in *run* method in WorkerThread (or in other method called from there) loop through list per thread. But I have problem with *java.util.ConcurrentModificationException*. What am I doing wrong?

```
for (String id : listOfIDs) {   
  listForThreads.add(id);
  if (listForThreads.size() >= 100) {
     Runnable worker = new WorkerThread(listForThreads);
     executor.execute(worker);
     listForThreads.clear();
   }
}
....
public static class WorkerThread implements Runnable {

    private List<String> listForThreads;
    public WorkerThread (List<String> listForThreads) {
        this.listForThreads = listForThreads;
    }
public void run() {
  for (String id : listForThreads) {
     process(id);
}   
} ....
```

I have thought that I will only process more IDs in one thread and not id per thread. Is it possible to use ExecutorService for run some processes in 'batches'?

Comment: Can you show the code for the process method? [ConcurrentModificationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) happens when you are modifiying (adding/removing elements) a Collection, while at the same time iterating over it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is wrong here in this section

```
for (String id : listOfIDs) {   
  listForThreads.add(id);
  if (listForThreads.size() >= 100) {
     Runnable worker = new WorkerThread(listForThreads);
     executor.execute(worker);
     listForThreads.clear();
   }
}
```

You should not make modifications while iterating the list. Here you are sharing **the same list instance with worker threads**. Which are iterating over the same instance of list  and you are clearing the list concurrently(at the same time) in the main thread. Ideally **You should create a copy of ArrayList** whenever sharing with other threads which only do Read only operation.
Create copy of ArrayList  using **listForThreads.toArray(new String[listForThreads.size()]) **
or by cloning the given list see answer to this question [Java ArrayList copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536094/java-arraylist-copy)