# Trouble returning copy of a List in java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a class that goes like this:

```
  public class People {
        private ArrayList<Person> people;
        ...
    }
```

Inside this class I want to create a method that that returns a copy of the array `people`, since it is private and I  want to avoid privacy leaks.

I have been trying to use this method as suggested in other threads and variations of it but with no success:

```
public ArrayList<Person> getPeople() {
        return new ArrayList<Person>(people);
}
```

However, I get the compilation error message:

```
 error: no suitable constructor found for ArrayList(ArrayList<Person>)
```

UPDATE:

I am using `import java.util.ArrayList;`

More detailed compilation error message:

```
  constructor ArrayList.ArrayList(int) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; ArrayList<Person> cannot be converted to int) 
 constructor ArrayList.ArrayList(Collection<? extends Person>) is not applicable
 (argument mismatch; ArrayList<Person> cannot be converted to Collection<? extends Person>)
```

UPDATE 2:

Apparetly, on a minimal working example it works. Certainly, the mistake should be somewhere else, and this is just a side effect.

Comment: Are you sure you're using `java.util.ArrayList`?

Comment: Is this a classic `java.util.ArrayList`, or are you hiding it by your own class?

Comment: post your entire code also with import statements

Comment: I am importing `java.util.ArrayList `.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536094/java-arraylist-copy.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE].

Comment: You probably have your own class called `ArrayList` that's hiding the import.

Comment: What happens if you prefix it with `java.util.ArrayList`?  That is, `return new java.util.ArrayList<Person>(people);`?  What do you get for doing that?

Comment: You are definitely hiding some messy code. Show it.  Like where does `constructor ArrayList.ArrayList(int) is not applicable` come from?

Answer (score 1):

java.util.ArrayList is a class that implements java.util.List. It is better to have your variable declared as an interface and for your methods to return an interface so you hide your implementation from code that uses your class.

```
public class People {
    private List<Person> people;
    ...
}


public List<Person> getPeople() {
    return new ArrayList<Person>(people);
}
```

That would be better. Also, is Person a mutable object? If so, your getPeople method needs to make a deep copy of the people List to preserve encapsulation.